# IIS seems to send email twice

Tags: iis, exchange, asp-classic

we have a request page in our website that send email to confirm the request. It seem that whenever this page is accessed, some (not all of them) are sent more than once at different time, sometime hours apart. The code (which is an old ASP page) looks fine as it sends only once to the recipient. So I doubt it's a programming related problem.

When looking at the Exchange server, the tech told me that he seems to be receiving the request twice at different time, so the problem comes from what's between the code and Exchange. My hypothesis is that IIS seem to 'remember' the page and rerun it for some reason.

Any hint on where to start?

We have IIS 6 (in french if it makes any difference) with Exchange 2007. IIS is running on a Windows Server 2003 machine (virtual machine I believe) in a DMZ. I don't know about Exchange.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by looking at IIS logfiles and see if there was multiple request made to the page. If yes, then it is normal. If no, then i would check the client ip from where the request for the email page started. This may just be some virus or malware which may be getting triggered after sometime.
IIS won't trigger any page on it's own (even from it's cache) until it is actually requested.

Comment: So I understand correctly, indexing or anything like will never cause the page to be request from the IIS server?

Comment: You send emails on a GET request? Indexing will hardly fill out the forms for the email, or? ;) Or do you send an email just when opening the page... what for?